# Is there any JS method to parse date only by providing month and year as arguments?

Tags: javascript

I'm working in a JavaScript date picker. I need to parse date by providing month and year. For example, if I'm giving argument as '01/2019', the output should be `Tue Jan 1 2019 00:00:00 GMT 05 30`. I'm aware this can be achieved by using `.toUTCString()` only if the argument should be a valid date i.e., it should be in the format of `dd mm yyyy`. But in my case, the format should be `mm yyyy`. Is there any JS built-in method to achieve this?

**Additional Info**:  Since date(dd) is not provided, the first date of the input month(mm) can be taken.
01/2019 -   Tue Jan 1 2019 00:00:00 GMT 05 30

Comment: Please add the code what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the native `Date` constructor, just reverse the month and year first:

```js
const reverse = americanDate => americanDate.split('/').reverse().join('.')
const jan2019 = new Date(reverse('01/2019')),
      feb2019 = new Date(reverse('2/2019')),
      // Date also works with 2 numbers: (month is 0-based)
      mar1990 = new Date(1990, 2)
      
console.log(jan2019, feb2019, mar1990)
```

Comment: Yes. It does only if the format specifier is `yyyy/mm`. My case is `mm/yyyy`

Comment: Well, just reverse the two numbers, for example `'01/2019'.split('/').reverse().join('/')`

Comment: @Jeyanth see my snippet hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete your requirement why don't you adding static `01/` as a `dd` in your `01/2019`(`mm/yyyy`) format

```
var currentDate = "01/2019";
var newDate = "01/"+currentDate;
var printDate = new Date(newDate);
document.write(printDate)
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5dqt41az/)

Comment: That works, too

Comment: Yes. We can also use native method to achieve the required format.






   `var mm = '01';

    var yy = '2019';

   console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(yy,mm-1)));`

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to achieve your goal and using the `Date` class of JavaScript.

You can pass a `string` literal date and parse it by instantiating to `Date`

```
var date = new Date('2019/1');
console.log(date);

// Expected Output
// Tue Jan 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)
```

You can also use the overload function of the `Date` that separate the year, date, and month parameter.

```
var date = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
// The order of parameter in here is Date(yyyy, mm, dd)
// The month starts at 0 so
// 0 = January
// 1 = February
// and so on...
// You can also pass string or integer in here
```

So you can manipulate desired output in here. For cleaner approach, you can get the data one by one, there are already set `getter` function for year, month, and date. Also for time too!

```
var date = new Date(2000, 0, 1);
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // adding 1 because the month is zero based
var year = date.getYear();

var output = month + '/' + year;

console.log(output);
// Expected Output
// 1/2000
```